# syntax issue with addition in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making some addition and substraction in my javascript, but I have strange results, I don't understanf whats wrong in my syntax:

```
var dy, i,diff;
dy=(lines_extrema[0]-lines_extrema[1])
for(i=1;i<=(narrow+1);i++){

  // Coordinates
  if(i==1) diff=(-lines_extrema[1]);
  else diff=(diff+lines[(0+3*(i-2))]);
}
```

lines and lines_extrema are read through get methods and are real. 
dy is fine, I have a real.
diff is fine for i=0 and them it returns things like that "20.9603-10.9".
What's wrong in my syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly `lines_extrema[0]` or `lines_extrema[1]` are of string types. Also, I guess this should be `diff=(-lines_extrema[1])` changed to `diff-=lines_extrema[1]`.. Share some fiddle link to see more into exact issue..

Comment: I don't think lines_extrema are the issue since dy is fine. I tried replacing  diff=(-lines_extrema[1]) by  diff=(0-lines_extrema[1]) but it is not working.

Comment: What is `lines` array? What are its contents type?

Comment: It's a real read with get method.

Comment: The XMLHttpRequest get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing operation on **string** variables instead of **number**s, so the addition is actually a concatenation.

To convert string to numbers, prefix them with "+". Example:

```
var extrema0 = +lines_extrema[0];
var extrema1 = +lines_extrema[1];
```

then use extrema0 and extrema1 to add/substract.

Comment: I don't think lines_extrema are the issue since dy is fine

Comment: Here come some of the most hated parts of javascript. When you try to substract 2 strings, they are converted to numbers. That's why dy is fine. But since you're still using "lines_extrema" and "lines" after, it can be converted back to strings

Comment: Example: var a = "5"; var b="4"; var c = a-b; => c is a number (1), but then if you do "c+b" you'll end up with the string "14".

Comment: ok, I can see that's now. Defining var y=+lines[(0+3*(i-2))] and them do diff=diff+y works. Thanks!